# Docker Compose & Volumes issues

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I have been trying to run the my docker-compose.yml file for 2-3 days and have spent so much time finding the fix on internet but nothing seems to be working. The host computer is Windows 10 and Docker computer is Linux.

Created volume using this command:
`docker volume create --driver local --opt type=none --opt device='C:\Users\Kishan\Desktop\db' --opt o=bind mssqldb`

and following is my docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '3.8'

services:
   db:
     image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest
     volumes:
       - mssqldb:/opt/var/mssql/data
     environment:
       - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
       - SA_PASSWORD=yourStrong@Password
       - COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=1
     restart: always
     ports:
       - "1433:1433"

   api:
     depends_on:
       - db
     entrypoint: ["./wait_for.sh", "db:1433", "-t", "3600", "--", "execute", "api"]
     image: api:latest
     ports:
       - "80:80"
     restart: always

volumes:
    mssqldb:
        external: true
```

I am not sure its runs without any error but I see no database files (MDF & LDF files) getting created in my `C:\Users\Kishan\Desktop\db`. Can somebody please help me?

Comment: For what you're doing (trying to expose a specific host directory to your container) I would think a bind mount would work better than a docker volume. Unfortunately, I don't have access to a Windows systems so I'm not able to either reproduce your problem or verify that my solution works.

Comment: The `\ ` is an escape in Linux, so if the command is parsed in a bash shell or by the Linux Docker engine, the path becomes: `C:UsersKishanDesktopdb`. The Linux path separator is `/`, and I don't think you want the `:`, so instead it might be `/c/Users/Kishan/Desktop/db` Like larsks, I don't have a windows machine to verify this on, and it may vary by which Windows install (e.g. WSL2 vs HyperV VM).

Comment: Thank you for the answers but both the answers didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the volume destination from `- mssqldb:/opt/var/mssql/data` to `- mssqldb:/var/opt/mssql`

Comment: Your suggestion worked but only changes I had to do is add data in the path. So my final path becomes `/var/opt/mssql/data`

Comment: Can you try again by recreating the volume ?

`docker volume rm mssqldb` and

`docker volume create --driver local --opt type=none --opt device=C:/Users/Kishan/Desktop/db --opt o=bind mssqldb`

Comment: I didn't have to create any external volumes. I changed the volumes line as `C:\Users\Kishan\Desktop\db:/var/opt/mssql/data` and its working.

Comment: Your solution is simpler, nice job!